# How to check if the number entered by the user is valid in 15 puzzle console application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, console-application

I was trying to make a 15 puzzle solution in C# in console, I almost done everything
except checking if the number in the array is above, below or next to the empty spot which is 0 in this array, please notice am a beginner so be easy on me
The class player simply takes input from the user but only valid inputs within the array
The index class returns the indices where the empty spot is '0' and return the indices of the user input
The board class swaps the empty spot with the user input

Here is the code

```
class Player
{
    public int playerInput;

    public int GetPlayer(Board board,Player player)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter a number from the board to switch with the empty spot:  ");
            playerInput = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if (playerInput <= 0 || playerInput > 15)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid input");
            }
            if(Board.IsLocation(board,player)==false)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Illegal move try again");
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        return playerInput;

    }

class Board
{
    public int[,] puzzle;
    public Board(int[,] Puzzle)
    {
        puzzle = Puzzle;
    }
    public void Swap(Player player, Board board)
    {
        Index index = new Index(0, 0);
        player.GetPlayer(board,player);
        index = index.GetIndex(board, player);
        for (var x = 0; x < 4; x++)
        {
            for (var y = 0; y < 4; y++)
            {
                if (board.puzzle[x, y] == 0)
                {
                    int temp = board.puzzle[x, y];
                    board.puzzle[x, y] = board.puzzle[index.x, index.y];
                    board.puzzle[index.x, index.y] = temp;
                }
            }
        }


    }

    static public bool IsLocation(Board board,Player player)
    {
        Index index = new(0, 0);
        Index embtyLocation = new(0, 0);
        embtyLocation = embtyLocation.GetEmptyLocation(board);
        index = index.GetIndex(board, player);

        if (board.puzzle[embtyLocation.x, embtyLocation.y] == 0)
        {
            if (board.puzzle[index.x, index.y] == board.puzzle[embtyLocation.x, embtyLocation.y + 1]) return true;
            if (board.puzzle[index.x, index.y] == board.puzzle[embtyLocation.x, embtyLocation.y - 1]) return true;
            if (board.puzzle[index.x, index.y] == board.puzzle[embtyLocation.x + 1, embtyLocation.y]) return true;
            if (board.puzzle[index.x, index.y] == board.puzzle[embtyLocation.x-1, embtyLocation.y]) return true;


        }
            return false;
    }

class Index
{
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public Index(int x, int y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    public Index GetIndex(Board board, Player player)
    {
        for (x = 0; x < 4; x++)
        {
            for (y = 0; y < 4; y++)
            {
                if (board.puzzle[x, y] == player.playerInput) return new Index(x, y);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    public Index GetEmptyLocation(Board board)
    {
        for (x = 0; x < 4; x++)
        {
            for (y = 0; y < 4; y++)
            {
                if (board.puzzle[x, y] == 0) return new Index(x, y);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Checking if the index of the entered number is exactly 1 different than the index of the empty spot in only one axis should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it thanks to you,
here is the code

```
static public bool IsLocation(Board board,Player player)
    {
        Index index = new(0, 0);
        Index embtyLocation = new(0, 0);
        embtyLocation = embtyLocation.GetEmptyLocation(board);
        index = index.GetIndex(board, player);

        if (embtyLocation.y >= 0 && embtyLocation.y!=3)
        {
            if (board.puzzle[index.x, index.y] == board.puzzle[embtyLocation.x, embtyLocation.y + 1]) return true;
        }
        if (embtyLocation.y < 4 && embtyLocation.y!=0)
        {
            if (board.puzzle[index.x, index.y] == board.puzzle[embtyLocation.x, embtyLocation.y - 1]) return true;
        }
        if (embtyLocation.x < 4 && embtyLocation.x!=0)
        {
            if (board.puzzle[index.x, index.y] == board.puzzle[embtyLocation.x - 1, embtyLocation.y]) return true;
        }
        if (embtyLocation.x >= 0 && embtyLocation.x!=3)
        {
            if (board.puzzle[index.x, index.y] == board.puzzle[embtyLocation.x + 1, embtyLocation.y]) return true;
        }


        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Hi, @Amr Ali. Does this solution solve your problem? If it is solved, you can click ‘✔’ to accept it as an answer. It is helpful for community members to solve the similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this

```
if (y > 0 && board.puzzle[index.x, index.y - 1] == 0) return true;
if (y < 4 && board.puzzle[index.x, index.y-1] == 0) return true;
if (x > 0 && board.puzzle[index.x-1, index.y] == 0) return true;
if (x < 4 && board.puzzle[index.x+1, index.y] == 0) return true;
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but still the same Index Out Of Range Exception 
error happens, but thanks for answering anyways